# Restore Latest Copy of Full and Differential database From Azure Blob Container

Tags: sql-server, restore, powershell, azure

I'm trying to work out how to Restore the Latest Backup of a Database that is held on Azure Storage Blobs. This container contains other backups from different databases on a server but I'm only interested in Restoring the Latest Full and Diff Backup for a particular Database

I need to do this automatically via powershell or something and schedule it from a job.

I've looked at:
Restore-SqlDatabase but can't see how it will use Azure credentials
DBATools.io - Again nothing to pass in Azure credentials
AzCopy - How do you get the latest Backup?
Azure PowerShell - Again as above.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Did you look at [SQL Server Managed Backup to Microsoft Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/sql-server-managed-backup-to-microsoft-azure?view=sql-server-2017)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Restore-DbaDatabase](https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/dbatools/blob/development/functions/Restore-DbaDatabase.ps1) does have `-AzureCredential` as parameter.

Suggest you to download the [latest version of dbatools](https://dbatools.io/download/) and try it.

Alternatively, you can try [ps_restoregene](https://paulbrewer.wordpress.com/ps_restoregene/) - which is powershell based script written by Paul brewer. (I have used it and its a life saver :-) )

Comment: Thanks Kin. I must have missed that parameter :) I'll take another look.

Comment: Wen't with ps_restoregene. Working Great! Thank you so much for the pointer.